# Python tkinter combobox and dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, combobox

I am new in Python and have stuck in the following problem. I have created a dictionary with material as Key and refractive index as Value.

From a combo-box a user chooses the material. At the same time, I would like to show the refractive index of the selected material. But I can't get it worked!
Here-under is my code. Thanks for your help.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def main():

    materialDict = {'XO': 1.415, 'XO2': 1.424, 'Opt-EX': 1.431, 'TYRO-97': 1.44, 'AC-100': 1.415, 'Paragon': 1.442}

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("1600x800+0+0")
    root.title("TEST Form")
    root.configure(bg='Dodgerblue4')

    label_material = Label(root, text='Choose Material', bd=3, width=20, height=3).grid(row=0, column=1)
    var_material = StringVar()
    combo_material = ttk.Combobox(root, values=list(materialDict.keys()), justify=CENTER, textvariable=var_material)
    combo_material.grid(row=0, column=2)
    combo_material.current(0)

    label_selected = Label(root, text="Here I want to print the value of the combobox selected item ")
    label_selected.grid(row=1, column=3)

    root.mainloop()

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: There are two methods you can use. `combo_material.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callback_method)` or `var_material.trace('w', callback_method)` but because of your non-class structure, updating a label from those methods might not be easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done using a `lambda`. You need to bind the `<<ComboboxSelected>>` event to a *callback* function. Instead of writing a separate function, I have done the label configuration there itself.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def main():

    materialDict = {'XO': 1.415, 'XO2': 1.424, 'Opt-EX': 1.431, 'TYRO-97': 1.44, 'AC-100': 1.415, 'Paragon': 1.442}

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("TEST Form")
    root.configure(bg='Dodgerblue4')

    tk.Label(root, text='Choose Material', bd=3).grid(row=0, column=0)
    var_material = tk.StringVar()
    combo_material = ttk.Combobox(root, values=list(materialDict.keys()), justify="center", textvariable=var_material)
    combo_material.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda event: label_selected.config(text=materialDict[var_material.get()]))
    combo_material.grid(row=0, column=1)
    combo_material.current(0)

    label_selected = tk.Label(root, text="Not Selected")
    label_selected.grid(row=1, column=1)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually need the dictionary value (refractive index) printed on the label upon selecting the material in the combobox.

Comment: @PaymanRajai Edited. Have a look. You just had to reference it with `materialDict[...]`.